# Changing Time Zone Abbreviation in javascript date object

Tags: javascript, php, date, timezone, strtotime

How to format **Time Zone Abbreviation** in javascript date object

while taking `new Date()` object in javascript, it produce output as

`Thu Oct 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` in **windows** and

`Thu Oct 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)` in **Linux**...

What i need is the output in (IST), so I can convert the date using `strtotime()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert date to another timezone in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: @Glavić no, the question is how to convert "`India Standard Time`" to "`IST`" in the output of `Date` objects. That's a different question, and different solution.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need this conversion. Just using the `(India Standard Time)` suffix, or no suffix at all, will work just fine. For example:

```php
echo(strtotime("Thu Oct 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)") . " / " .
     strtotime("Thu Oct 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530") . " / " .
     strtotime("Thu Oct 30 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"));
```

Returns

```
1414627200 / 1414627200 / 1414627200
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/myP1I7mb).

So my answer to your question is that I don't think it's possible to get the official timezone abbreviation, but my solution to your problem is to simply use the format you already have (or if the suffix is causing problems when it's in another language, simply omit the suffix).

Alternatively, you can convert the timezone to UTC first, and then feed that to the PHP:

```
//some other way to generate this Date object is of course fine too
var d = new Date(/*your date object*/);

//converts it from ms -> sec, to the format PHP uses
var unix = Math.floor(d.getTime() / 1000);
```

Comment: Ok Ok...but in my server the third output is not getting

Comment: Then I suggest using the string without the suffix. The `GMT+0530` part should already handle the timezone.

Comment: i am not passing the data object, it getting from jQuery calander